# How to register a custom IObjectModelValidator with The DI of ASP.NET MVC core

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanted to custom the validation of asp.net mvc core. My main objective was to bind interfaces in the action method.
I found a solution by reading this excellent post: [Model binding interfaces: fixing server side validation](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2017/04/06/Model-binding-interfaces-fixing-server-side-validation.aspx).

After implementing the interface IObjectModelValidator, and  configure services in the startuo class, i was wondering why the validation process doesn't call my new objectModelValidator.

When i check in my action  by doing this instruction : `requestServices.GetRequiredService<IObjectModelValidator>()` i found only the defaultObjectModelValidator.

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 2):

I found the error by debugging the source of Asp.net MVC core, i was using the method tryAddSingleton instead of AddSingleton in the ConfigureServices method.
The first method checks if there is already a service whith the same type before adding a service and by that it wasn't adding my second service.
By changing TryAddSingleton by AddSingleton it works!

```
services.AddSingleton<IObjectModelValidator>(s =>
            {
                var options = s.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value;
                var modelMetadataProvider = s.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();
                return new EnhancedObjectModelValidator(modelMetadataProvider, options.ModelValidatorProviders);
            });
```